# Cosmos DB Mongo API Date Filtering Not Working

Tags: mongodb, .net-core, azure-cosmosdb, mongodb-.net-driver

I've got the following model inserted into an Azure Cosmos DB MongoDB collection, using the MongoDB .NET Driver. I'm attempting to query on the "EventDates.EndDate" field and so far, have been completely unsuccessful.

My object model is defined as:

**Event.cs**

```
namespace BAH.API.BAHEvents.Models
{
    public class Event

    {

        [Required]
        [AutoExpand]
        public List<EventDate> EventDates { get; set; }

        [Key]
        [BsonId]
        public Guid UniqueId { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**EventDates.cs**

```
namespace BAH.API.BAHEvents.Models
{
    public class EventDate
    {
        public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }

        [BsonId]
        public Guid Id { get; set; }

        public DateTime? RegistrationEndDate { get; set; }

        public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**MongoDB Document**

```
{
    "_id" : {
        "$binary" : "RERgIgY190CTyABU/gt84g==",
        "$type" : "03"
    },
    "EventDates" : [
        {
            "_id" : {
                "$binary" : "B0ectlvls0WQIQQr1hcUHA==",
                "$type" : "03"
            },
            "EndDate" : {
                "$date" : 1522774800000
            },
            "RegistrationEndDate" : {
                "$date" : 1522645200000
            },
            "StartDate" : {
                "$date" : 1522771200000
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

**Query Expression**

```
var eventsCollection = db.GetCollection<Event>("collection")
    .WithReadPreference(ReadPreference.Nearest)
    .AsQueryable()
    .Where(e => e.EventDates.Any(ed => ed.EndDate >= DateTime.UtcNow));
```

At present, when I query the EndDate, either through the .NET Driver or directly within the Azure Portal, I get no results at all. I've tried so many different things to get this working, including:

1. Adding the "[BsonDateTimeOptions(Representation = BsonType.Document, Kind = DateTimeKind.Utc)]" attribute to EndDate. This stores the DateTime in mongo with the "Ticks" included, but didn't change my results at all
2. Changing the Type of EndDate to DateTimeOffset
3. Storing EndDate as a long of Ticks and querying against that
4. Adding an index in Cosmos for the EndDate property
5. I installed mongodb locally, and ran my code against it and was able to query by EndDate successfully
6. I'm currently developing with .net core, on my mac, but I've tried using a windows virtual machine as well, with no change. I've written nearly the same code the node.js and mongoose, and was able to successfully query on dates
7. I can query on other fields, like UniqueId, without issue

What in the wide wide world of sports am I doing wrong? This seems like it should be such a simple thing to do, but I'm getting nowhere fast!

Comment: Just a thought, have you looked at the Mongo query that is being sent? You can subscribe to the `CommandStartedEvent` to see the command.

Edit: to clarify, whenever I have a problem like this I like to debug in the Mongo shell, so we need to know what the command is.

Comment: I had tried that, yes. I even copied the query directly from the command output to Robo 3T and was unable to get any results back. I've got a ticket open with MS now, hoping to get some answers from that.

Comment: I did eventually find however that I was able to query dates if I used `cm.MapMember(e => e.EndDate).SetSerializer(new DateTimeOffsetSerializer(BsonType.String));` in my model mapping (though, I haven't yet tried this with the model mentioned above).